# Remove quantity from old and add to new

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

### The goal

When change the category of a product, I want to decrease the quantity of the products in the old category of this product and increase quantity into the new category.

### The problem

I know I will do it with a trigger, but I do not know the syntax.

### What I already have tried

I made a sketch, hehe:

[image: Sketch]

### Details

I'm using **MySQL**.

***Categories table structure***:

[image: Category table]

***Categories and Products relationship table structure***:

[image: Relationship]

### What I already have thought:

I know, it is not right, but just to illustrate my philosophy:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `updateQuantitiesOfProductsInCategories` AFTER UPDATE ON `products_category_relationship` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE categories
    SET categories.ProductsQuantity = OLD.categories.ProductsQuantity -1
    AND NEW.categories.ProductsQuantity +1
    WHERE bm_categories.Id = OLD.ProductId;
END
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but to me your model definition seems really inaccurate...

Comment: Seriously, @Sebas? Why?

Comment: It seems weird to me that a product could belong to 2 categories at the same time, according to what you're doing with the trigger. But as I said I'm probably wrong, you know better your business.

Comment: @Sebas A product cannot belong to two categories. I'm removing a product from one category and adding another. I'm just updating the count.

Comment: Then you should not have a table for the relation, it should be a foreign key...

Comment: @Sebas Can you give me an example?

Comment: If your relation is a 0->n or a 1->n there's a foreign key. If this is a n-n there's a relation table. The product table should have an id_category field pointing to an id on the category table (I suppose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update syntax should be something like this:

```
update categories
    set ProductQuantity = ProductQuantity - 1
    where id = old.categoryid;

 update categories
    set ProductQuantity = ProductQuantity + 1
    where id = new.categoryid;
```